# Sql Selecting one of many child tables

Tags: sql

I am not new to SQL but I am not a db manager/designer by trade and so have hit a bit of a conundrum. I have a parent table(parent table has shared attributes of child tables) that has something like 8 children. When I query the db I will require the data from  the parent table and only one child at a time, however I am having trouble determining how to communicate which child table to pull from. The parent and child tables share an id. A field in the parent table has the potential for being a decider for which child to draw from. Example:

`parent
id      machine
1       N1
2       S8
3       P6`

contains only records associated with parent records that have 'N' type machines(N1, N2, N3, ...).
`child1
id      ...some other columns
1`

contains only records associated with parent records that have 'S' type machines(S1, S2, S3, ...).
`child2
id      ...some other columns
2`

contains only records associated with parent records that have 'P' type machines(P1, P2, P3, ...).
`child3
id      ...some other columns
3`

I see several logical possibilities here that don't seem very efficient:
1) Search each child table in turn for the id of the record from the parent.

2) Create a view with a join statement which houses all the child table records appended to the associated parent records. Wouldn't this turn into one giant glob of null value checkered sweetness?  [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/30d10/1)

3) create one view per child table that concatenates parent and child records into one. Create some mechanism in another language that translates a machine into its type (ex: if I want a record for `N1`, said code would set the query 'table' for the view containing child1(The `N` type machine table). (perhaps the best option of the three???)  [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03959/2)

I cannot help but feel like I'm missing something here, some SQL magic that will make this problem seem trivial, but a scowering of the inter-webs has produced nothing. Anything you can give me would be greatly appreciated. Thanks SO.

Comment: Here I assume all `CHILD` tables contain same kind of columns.Is it possible you can Insert all `CHILD` tables data in one new table, with an extra `MACHINE_TYPE` indicator column like P6, S8 . `MACHINE_TYPE` will help you in `JOIN` with `PARENT` Table also.

Comment: unfortunately no, the child tables all contain different columns, so it would make a huge table full of nulls. I'd like to avoid that if I can.

Comment: What I can think of now is two step solution . Create a new table with 2 columns i.e.  `MACHINE_TYPE` and  `CONCATENATED` all other columns with delimiter like comma . This table will help you in `JOIN` . Now for select you can `CONVERT` delimited text column in Rows easily with in built functions .

Answer (score 0):

A way you could do those `JOIN`s is by making a `LEFT JOIN` to all of the tables with the type of product that it is, and then using `COALESCE` for all of them in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT      p.id, 
            P.machine, 
            P.someField, 
            COALESCE(C1.field, C2.field, C3.field)  field
FROM        parent  P
LEFT JOIN   child1  C1  ON  C1.id = P.id
                        AND LEFT(P.machine, 1) = 'N'
LEFT JOIN   child2  C2  ON  C2.id = P.id
                        AND LEFT(P.machine, 1) = 'S'
LEFT JOIN   child3  C3  ON  C3.id = P.id
                        AND LEFT(P.machine, 1) = 'P';
```

However, doing it this way is very expensive.

A better way of doing this would be to have a single `Child` table that had the type of machine that it was in it (e.g.: a `MachineType Char(1)` column that just had `N`, `S`, `P`, etc. in it), as opposed to using 8 different tables.

Another option would be to use `UNION ALL` to bring in the items separately:

```
SELECT      p.id, 
            P.machine, 
            P.someField, 
            C1.field    field
FROM        parent  P
JOIN        child1  C1  ON  C1.id = P.id
WHERE       LEFT(P.machine, 1) = 'N'

UNION ALL

SELECT      p.id, 
            P.machine, 
            P.someField, 
            C2.field    field
FROM        parent  P
JOIN        child2  C2  ON  C2.id = P.id
WHERE       LEFT(P.machine, 1) = 'S'

UNION ALL

SELECT      p.id, 
            P.machine, 
            P.someField, 
            C3.field    field
FROM        parent  P
JOIN        child3  C3  ON  C3.id = P.id
WHERE       LEFT(P.machine, 1) = 'P'
```

Comment: Child Table contains different kind of columns.

Comment: @minatverma I'm sure they do, but I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: The problem with combining the child tables is each one contains different sets of columns, I don't want to end up with more empty values than filled values. I think I'm starting to come to the conclusion that I need 8 different views each containing a parent and child set of columns... Other wise I end up with lots of null/empty values.

Comment: @JoeMilo That is an option, you can create a view for each type and combine them into one query via a `UNION ALL` for each (essentially that's exactly what my second query suggestion is doing)

Comment: @Siyual I see where you are going with this, however, something I neglected to mention is that the tables all have varying numbers of rows. I just tested your code, adding a second column to child3, it doesn't work with varying numbers of rows, so I am stuck querying several views instead but I do really like your code snippet, it is a pretty cool use of union and join.

Comment: @JoeMilo I'm not quite sure I'm following.  In the query you're wanting to build, are you wanting to show different columns for each of the different product types?  If that is the case, you cannot do that with a single query, unless you want to show all of the columns for all of the products you wish to select from.  In that case, you're better off making a view for each of the different products.

Comment: @JoeMilo ... If you're wanting, however, to display a *specific* field that is common amongst all of the products, and are just trying to do `JOIN` management to get to the correct table, then this would be what my answer was addressing.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot each child table into column names/values and union them together in a view if that is a more favorable output.  Based on your SQL Fiddle:

```
--Unpivoted Children 
CREATE VIEW unpvt_child AS
--N Machine Children
SELECT 
  unpvt.id,
  unpvt.col_name,
  unpvt.col_value
FROM
  (SELECT id, c1_field1
   FROM child1) p
UNPIVOT
  (col_value FOR col_name IN
     (c1_field1)
)AS unpvt
UNION ALL

--S Machine Children
SELECT 
  unpvt.id,
  unpvt.col_name,
  unpvt.col_value
FROM
  (SELECT id, c2_field1
   FROM child2) p
UNPIVOT
  (col_value FOR col_name IN
     (c2_field1)
)AS unpvt;
```

This gives you an output like this:

```
id, col_name, col_value
1, c1_field1, N machine stuff
2, c2_field1, S machine stuff
```

And if I understand the schema, the primary key is id which is one-to-one to the child tables, so the new join is simple:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  parent p
LEFT JOIN
  unpvt_child c ON c.id = p.id;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa5f33/1

Your final output can look something like this:

```
id, machine, someField, child_attribute, child_value
1, N1, blah, c1_field1, N machine stuff
2, S8, moreblah, c2_field1, S machine stuff
```